# Getting the path of a an item on using UrlAction and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecb-menu, development

I have a custom ECB menu item. I want to get the path of the file that has been right clicked and alert it using JavaScript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetAttributeFromItemTable(itemTable, "Url", "ServerUrl");
```

This will get the /path/to/item.